# Calculate number of comparison and moves in quicksort C++

Tags: c++, arrays, quicksort

I am having this assignment to develop a program that implement quicksort algorithm with the first element in the array as pivot value. I already manage to do the sorting by using 20 elements in an array.

Now, I want to calculate number of comparison and moves occur during sorting process. I already try this code but the output doesn't seem right. The comparison and moves keep print out repeatedly. How can I print out the moves and comparison only once? Hopefully someone willing to help me. Thanks in advance.

Code of comparison and moves :

```
int partition1(int arr[], int start, int end) { //select first element as pivot value
int pivot = arr[start];
int L = start + 1;
int R = end;
int temp = 0;
int compr = 0;
int move = 0;

while (true) {
    while ((L < R) && (arr[R] >= pivot)) {  //bringing R to the left
        --R;
        compr++;
    } 
    while ((L < R) && (arr[L] < pivot)) {   //bringing R to the right
        ++L;
        compr++;
    }
    if (L == R) {   //If they coincide
        break;
    } 
    //swapping L and R
    temp = arr[L];
    arr[L] = arr[R];
    arr[R] = temp;
    move += 2;
}

cout << "Comparison : " << compr << endl;
cout << "Moves : " << move << endl;

if (pivot <= arr[L]) {  //special case
    return start;
} 
else {
    arr[start] = arr[L];  //real pivot
    arr[L] = pivot;
    return L;
} }
```

and this one is quick sort function :

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int start, int end) {
int boundary;
if (start < end) {
    boundary = partition1(arr, start, end);
    quickSort(arr, start, boundary - 1);
    quickSort(arr, boundary + 1, end);
} }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `while ((L < R) && (arr[R] >= pivot))` cycle there is one more comparation if condition is `false`, that's why you should increment `compr` **before** both cycles:

```
int partition1(int arr[], int start, int end, int & compr, int & move) { //select first element as pivot value
int pivot = arr[start];
int L = start + 1;
int R = end;
int temp = 0;
//int compr = 0;
//int move = 0;
while (true) {
compr++; // !!!
while ((L < R) && (arr[R] >= pivot)) {  //bringing R to the left
    --R;
    compr++;
} 
compr++; // !!!
while ((L < R) && (arr[L] < pivot)) {   //bringing R to the right
    ++L;
    compr++;
}
... // the same lines to the end of function partition1, except of printing compr and move
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int start, int end, int & compr, int & move) {
int boundary;
if (start < end) {
    boundary = partition1(arr, start, end, compr, move);
    quickSort(arr, start, boundary - 1, compr, move);
    quickSort(arr, boundary + 1, end, compr, move);
} }

int main() {
    int compr = 0;
    int move = 0;
    quickSort( { 3, 2, 4, 1 }, 0, 3, compr, move );

    cout << "Total comparison : " << compr << endl;
    cout << "Total moves : " << move << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define `compr` and `move` as **global** variables (only for debugging purposes) and then print values in the end of the run.

Comment: thank you sir for your suggestion. I just wanna ask, is my codes to calculate move and comparison correct?